# how to debug SQL(oracle) query logic

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, logic

I have written the SQL queries using inner join with two tables. Syntax is right and but when I am executing the it is NOT producing desired output.

How to debug the logical part of it in SQL. If it is PL/SQL we can either use DBMS_OUPUT.put_line() or use single step debugger to find out the logic working or not.
How to do thee similar one in SQL.

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to take time  to help you, please spend a little time crafting a usable question.  See these links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and http://sscce.org/

Comment: Are you referring to MySQL or Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: or sql server perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug a SQL statement just like you debug a PL/SQL program - by breaking it up into smaller chunks, and seeing if the actual behaviour matches up with the expected behaviour.

For example, if you have a query like this:

```
SELECT a, b + c
FROM x JOIN y ON (x.id = y.id);
```

And the results you're getting are not what you expected, you might first run these two queries:

```
SELECT id, a, b FROM y;

SELECT id, c FROM y;
```

Examine the results, then "join" the results in your head (i.e. look for all rows in the two result sets where the ID matches).

Somewhere along the way you'll discover the reason why the query isn't returning the results you expect - or, you'll discover your expected results were wrong in the first place.